# Enqueueing scripts selectively & activation where needed

Tags: functions, wp-enqueue-script

If I enqueue my scripts selectively, for instance I have a slider I only want to load on homepage, which is activated in main-js, e.g:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'main-js' );
if ( is_front_page() ) {    
  wp_enqueue_script( 'slider' );
}
```

What is then the best way to do this? because all my jquery is in main-js and is applied to every page, so the call to activate the slider (e.g. `$('#slider').slider();`) only applies to homepage?

Hopefully that makes sense and appreciate if anyone could explain best way to do this.

UPDATE:

So in functions.php I have:

```
// Hook in function with javascript files using the wp_enqueue_scripts hook 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_javascript_files' );

// Register javascript files
function load_javascript_files() {

wp_register_script( 'slider', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/slider.js', array('jquery'), '', true );
wp_register_script( 'main-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array('jquery'), '', true );

wp_enqueue_script( 'main-js' );
if ( is_front_page() ) {  
  wp_enqueue_script( 'slider' );
}

}
```

And main.js has generic code, e.g:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  //activate slider
  $('#slider').slider();  

    // scroll body to 0px on click
    $('a[href=#top]').click(function () {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 'slow');
        return false;
    });

    //add opacity to linked images
    $("a img").hover(function(){
       $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": 0.7}, 200);
       },function(){
       $(this).stop().animate({"opacity": 1}, 300);
    });
  });
```

So I need the slider activation only to apply to the homepage.

Comment: Where in your Theme is the enqueue code? Is it in `functions.php`? If not, then where? And is what you've included in your question the *entire* relevant code?

Comment: Yes that's correct, it's in functions.php - have updated question.

Comment: Please check both instances of your code. You switch which of the the `main-js` and `slider` enqueue calls is wrapped in the `is_front_page()` conditional. Which one is correct?

Comment: woops, mistyped, have updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're only enqueueing scripts when they're needed, you can check in JS if the plugin's namespace exists before trying to use it:

```
if( $.fn.slider ) {
    $('#slider').slider();
}
```

or another option is to pass some script vars via [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script):

```
$wpa_script_data = array(
    'is_front_page' => is_front_page(),
    'slider_options' => array(
        'speed' => 6000
    )
);

wp_localize_script(
    'main-js',
    'wpa_vars',
    $wpa_script_data
);
```

then in js:

```
if( wpa_vars.is_front_page ) {
    $('#slider').slider({
        'speed' : wpa_vars.slider_options.speed
    });
}
```

Comment: Great thanks! This is what I have been looking for. Checking the plugins namespace works great.